# when set the request header inside the promise call, the header not set to server

Tags: javascript

I have used XMLHttpRequest and Promise. I will set the additional header in pormise callback function(then()), the header not set to request and facing the 'object's state must be opended'. But i have opened before set the request. please find the code snippet for your reference.

```
DOMException: Failed to execute 'setRequestHeader' on 'XMLHttpRequest': The object's state must be OPENED.
```

```
 <div class="html5_upload">
        <input type="file" id="upload" class="uploadBtn" name="UploadFiles" />

        <button class="uploadBtn" onclick="uploadFiles()">Upload File</button>
    </div>

    <script>

    function uploadFiles() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var file = document.getElementById('upload').files[0];
        var formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('UploadFiles', file); 
        xhr.open('POST', 'https://localhost:44310/api/values/save', true);

        new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            resolve();
        }).then(function () { 
            xhr.setRequestHeader('custom', 'new');
        });
        xhr.onerror = function (args) {
            console.log('error occurs..!');
        }
        xhr.send(formData); 
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Why are you calling `.send` before `.setRequestHeader`?

Comment: Check if xhr.send(formData); is executed before the Promise resolves. i.e. then part is executed after the request is sent.

Answer (score 0):

I think your `xhr.send(formData)` should be inside the `.then()`. Could you try the below code and see if it works as desired.

```
function uploadFiles() {
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var file = document.getElementById('upload').files[0];
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append('UploadFiles', file); 
xhr.open('POST', 'https://localhost:44310/api/values/save', true);

new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    resolve();
}).then(function () { 
    xhr.setRequestHeader('custom', 'new');
    xhr.send(formData); // Changed position from original code

});
xhr.onerror = function (args) {
    console.log('error occurs..!');
}
}
```